# Why do Elixir Regexes break when they reach a certain length?

Tags: regex, erlang, elixir

See this example:

```
str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
Regex.match? ~r/a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/, str
#=> true
Regex.match? ~r/a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/, str
#=> false
```

Note that it does not break if `str` gets longer, only if I add more `a?`s to the Regular Expression.

Comment: This is called catastrophical backtracking. Do not use `a?a?`... just use `a*`.

Comment: This behaviour was discovered while comparing the backtracking performance of various RegEx implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Wiktor pointed out, this regex causes exponential backtracking in some Regex implementations, including the one Erlang uses (PCRE). The reason `match?` returns a plain `false` instead of throwing an error is because Erlang's `:re.run/3` returns a `:nomatch` if it hits this limit by default:

```
iex(1)> str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
iex(2)> re = ~r/a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/
~r/a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/
iex(3)> Regex.match?(re, str)
false
iex(4)> :re.run(str, re.re_pattern)
:nomatch
```

`:re.run/3` can be made to report this error by passing `:report_errors`, to confirm that this Regex did hit the limit:

```
iex(5)> :re.run(str, re.re_pattern, [:report_errors])
{:error, :match_limit}
```

From the documentation:

> The following are the possible runtime errors:
>
> `match_limit`
>
> The PCRE library sets a limit on how many times the
>   internal match function can be called. Defaults to 10,000,000 in the
>   library compiled for Erlang. If {error, match_limit} is returned, the
>   execution of the regular expression has reached this limit. This is
>   normally to be regarded as a nomatch, which is the default return
>   value when this occurs, but by specifying report_errors, you are
>   informed when the match fails because of too many internal calls.

The limit can be increased (which is usually a bad idea since the regex will be extremely slow and can cause a DoS attack if the Regex is supplied by the user):

```
iex(6)> :re.run(str, re.re_pattern, match_limit: 20_000_000)
{:match, [{0, 22}]}
```

Comment: Actually, increasing the limit is a workaround. Re-writing the pattern so that it becomes efficient is the right way to fix the issue.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew No, the question is about why the regex engine breaks, not how to optimize the pattern.

Comment: The point is: whenever a catastrophical backtracking is detected, the pattern must be enhanced, just increasing the limits is a workaround, not the fix.

Comment: Starting with 23 "a?" creates 2^23 possible cases, even if some implementation of `re` seems to be more clever, the pattern itself is not efficient. If the intent is to mach between 22 and 45 "a", the syntax a{22,45} should be used.

Comment: @Pascal a DFA-based Regex engine will handle that just fine. I just tried 44 `a?` followed by 44 `a` in Rust and it matches in ~300ns.

Comment: I have seen that there are many differences in regex implementation with big consequences on their limitation and performances. My remark was their only because I was wondering why someone would use this syntax which is highly "unreadable"  and prone to error. First it is not at all equivalent to `a*` so I guess that the purpose is really to find a series of `a` which length is in between Min and Max; the syntax tested "opens" 2^(Max-Min) options while the syntax `a{Min,Max}` "opens" only (Max-Min) options. IMHO this is a wiser option, just because it does not rely on the regex optimization.

Comment: @Pascal Based on what OP posted in a comment to the question, I think OP was only curious why Erlang returned the _wrong_ answer instead of running slow / crashing / returning an error as I'd expect other languages do. Pretty sure OP isn't actually using this regex for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not work because the optional patterns that all match at the same location in the string [cause *catastrophical backtracking* issue](https://regex101.com/r/wjbz1H/1).

Note that if you mean to match 0 or more symbols, just use `*` quantifier:

```
str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
Regex.match? ~r/a*aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/, str
                ^^
```

The `a*` will match 0 or more `a` symbols. See an [online Elixir demo](https://ideone.com/Rt54SK).

See more about [catastrophical backtracking here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).